# PHP: preg_match to str_replace?

Tags: php

At the moment I have this to check whether the $content is containing youtube link and if so then run the function youtubeFetchDataCallback():

```
if (preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", $content, $matches)) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

  foreach(array_unique($matches) as $m) {
    echo "
      $.getJSON (
        'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$m?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?',
        function(data) {
          youtubeFetchDataCallback(data, $id, '".$m."');
        } 
      );
    ";
  }

  echo '</script>';
}
```

This do work just fine although I wish to modify this so if there is a youtube link, remove it from the $content and run youtubeFetchDataCallback.

So by remove, maybe replace the youtubelink to '' (empty).

How can I do this? Thank you

UPDATE: Tried this so far:

```
if (preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", $content, $matches)) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

  foreach(array_unique($matches) as $m) {
    echo "
      $.getJSON (
        'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$m?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?',
        function(data) {
          youtubeFetchDataCallback(data, $id, '".$m."');
        } 
      );
    ";
  }

  echo '</script>';
}
$content = preg_replace("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", '', $content);
echo $content; 
?>
```

The videolink still is in the $content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to add the remote calls in one single Javascript block.

EDIT: It seems you want to remove all the link to youtube video, but if I understood the expression correctly the expression only matches some url params. Perhaps you could modify the regexp to match the whole url, and pass the youtube params as one or more capturing group to the callback.

Update (again) If you want to remove the link you may use a regexp like this:

```
'#<a(?:.+?)(?:(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+)(?:.+?)</a>#'
```

Update (again and again) This expression should cut out the whole URL because searches for anything that resembles the youtube domain, and then it goes straightforward until it finds a space (or a newline or a tab). You should also use the single quotes to surround this regexp.

```
'#(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com/(?:[^\s]*)#'
```

Comment: I would like to remove the link from the $content, how can I do this? forget about the rest

Comment: I updated the answer two times so the last one should be the good one. It *should* work, I hadn't the time to test it.

Comment: I did: $content = preg_replace("#<a(?:.+?)(?:(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+)(?:.+?)</a>#", '', $content); now still it shows the link when i echo $content

Comment: Could you provide a sample link that should be stripped out from `$content`?

Comment: I dont understand why in preg_match it detected the link without problems with this regex i had previously in preg_match: #(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+# , and now it wont detect the link`?

Comment: @Minkiele , ok I just tried to rename the variable that has the preg_replace with the regex, and now it seem to work, kinda. It strips out the videoID, so what remains is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=&feature=related

Comment: @Minkiele although only with the regex I had before, when I use yours it doesnt strip anything. Thank you in forward

Comment: @Karem my regex should cut the whole `<a href="http://youtube.com">Youtube link</a>` HTML thing. If you have to cut just the url then the expression is different. I'll shortly update my answer.

Comment: @Minkiele nice this works fine! Will this work no matter the youtube link is? I mean if it is not &feature=related but maybe &feature=whatever&fmt=18 etc etc?

Comment: Yes, it detects any character until it finds a space or a newline or a tab (or the end of `$content`).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: Ok i tried with it please see updated question, but the link is still in the $content